# How to unit test async Redux actions to mock ajax response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, redux

I am creating a middleware for making ajax requests using async actions. The middleware intercepts original action, performs ajax request, and re-`dispatch`es the original action along with the response from the `url`.

So, my Component would merely `dispatch` an action like this

```
onClick() {
    dispatch(ActionCreator.fetchUser());
}
```

Rest will be taken care by the middleware as shown [here](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/middleware/api.js).

My question is, what should I do for unit testing? Should I mock the `onClick` itself? or I should write a mocked middleware and forward the actions with the mocked response?

I am not sure which approach should I take. I tried [several stuff](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/546#issuecomment-134789273), but none of what I tried made sense to me.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Note: answer below is slightly outdated.

A much simpler updated approach is described [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1716).
You can still do it the other way too, though.

---

We now have [a section on testing async action creators](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#async-action-creators) in the official docs.

For async action creators using [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or other middleware, it’s best to completely mock the Redux store for tests. You can still use `applyMiddleware()` with a mock store, as shown below. You can also use [nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock) to mock the HTTP requests.

```
function fetchTodosRequest() {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODOS_REQUEST
  };
}

function fetchTodosSuccess(body) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODOS_SUCCESS,
    body
  };
}

function fetchTodosFailure(ex) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODOS_FAILURE,
    ex
  };
}

export function fetchTodos(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchTodosRequest());
    return fetch('http://example.com/todos')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(addTodosSuccess(json.body)))
      .catch(ex => dispatch(addTodosFailure(ex)));
  };
}
```

can be tested like:

```
import expect from 'expect';
import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from '../../actions/counter';
import * as types from '../../constants/ActionTypes';
import nock from 'nock';

const middlewares = [thunk];

/**
 * Creates a mock of Redux store with middleware.
 */
function mockStore(getState, expectedActions, onLastAction) {
  if (!Array.isArray(expectedActions)) {
    throw new Error('expectedActions should be an array of expected actions.');
  }
  if (typeof onLastAction !== 'undefined' && typeof onLastAction !== 'function') {
    throw new Error('onLastAction should either be undefined or function.');
  }

  function mockStoreWithoutMiddleware() {
    return {
      getState() {
        return typeof getState === 'function' ?
          getState() :
          getState;
      },

      dispatch(action) {
        const expectedAction = expectedActions.shift();
        expect(action).toEqual(expectedAction);
        if (onLastAction && !expectedActions.length) {
          onLastAction();
        }
        return action;
      }
    }
  }

  const mockStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
    ...middlewares
  )(mockStoreWithoutMiddleware);

  return mockStoreWithMiddleware();
}

describe('async actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  it('creates FETCH_TODO_SUCCESS when fetching todos has been done', (done) => {
    nock('http://example.com/')
      .get('/todos')
      .reply(200, { todos: ['do something'] });

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: types.FETCH_TODO_REQUEST },
      { type: types.FETCH_TODO_SUCCESS, body: { todos: ['do something']  } }
    ]
    const store = mockStore({ todos: [] }, expectedActions, done);
    store.dispatch(actions.fetchTodos());
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the 'fetch' here ?

Comment: Is there a example or doc to make test with redux thunk extra argument? This is confusing for me

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, I don't need to mock any store methods or anything. Its as simple as mocking the ajax request. I am using `superagent`, so I did it something like this

```
const mockResponse = {
    body: {
        data: 'something'
    }
};

spyOn(superagent.Request.prototype, 'end').and.callFake((cb) => {
    cb(null, mockResponse); // callback with mocked response
});

// and expect it to be called
expect(superagent.Request.prototype.end).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: This works too. In fact it can be even simpler: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1716